# using multiple by in a data table by loop

Tags: r, data.table

suppose I have a data table with three column `X1,X2,X3`, additional columns `V1,V2,...,VN`, and let `FUN` of type `mean, min, max`

`dt<-data.table(X1,X2,X3,V1,V2,...,VN)`

I want to run this in a loop:

```
dt[,Y112_mean:=mean(X1), by=list(V1,V2)]
dt[,Y113_mean:=mean(X1), by=list(V1,V3)]
...
dt[,Y11N_mean:=mean(X1), by=list(V1,VN)]
...
dt[,Yijk_mean:=mean(Xi), by=list(Vj,Vk)]
...
dt[,Yijk_max:=max(Xi), by=list(Vj,Vk)]
...
dt[,Yijk_min:=min(Xi), by=list(Vj,Vk)]
```

I tried to do this as follows:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
   for (j in 1:(N-1)) {
      for (k in (j+1):N) {
        for (FUN in c(mean,max,min)) {
   ...
   # get `mean(X1)` or `max(X2)` etc.
   e<-as.name(paste0(substitute(FUN,"(X",i,")"))

   # get `list(V1,V2)` or `list(V2,V3)` etc.
   f<-as.name(paste0("list(V",j,",",V",k,")"))

   # get `Y123_mean' etc.
   g<-as.name(paste0("Y",i,j,k,"_",substitute(FUN)))

   # get the column now (this doesn't work below).
   # e.g. of error `list(V1,V2)` not found.
   dt[,eval(g):=eval(e),by=eval(f)]
   ...
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Clearly, my application of `eval` or `data.table` might be wrong. I did notice in the `data.table` documentation there is a `.BY` and I tried a few combinations, but couldn't get that to work either.

Another alternative I tried was

`dt[,(paste0("Y",i,j,k,"_",substitute(FUN)):=FUN(dt[[paste0("X",i]]),by=eval(f)]`

but I got an error in the `eval(f)` part like `list(V1,V2)` not found

I suspect I might have done quite a few errors. What would be the correct syntax?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is the *minimal* and *reproducible* example:

suppose VN is  V4

```
X1<-seq(1,1000)
X2<-seq(1,1000)
X3<-seq(1,1000)
V1<-rep(seq(1,10),100)
V2<-rep(seq(1,5),200)
V3<-rep(seq(1,4),250)
V4<-rep(seq(1,2),500)
```

Comment: You should provide a *minimal and reproducible* example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code in order to create a single command string, which is evaluated with `eval` and `parse`. Note that `FUN` does not represent the function but its name here.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:(N-1)) {
    for (k in (j+1):N) {
      for (FUN in c("mean","max","min")) {
        ...
        # get `mean(X1)` or `max(X2)` etc.
        e <- paste0(FUN,"(X",i,")")

        # get `list(V1,V2)` or `list(V2,V3)` etc.
        f <- paste0("list(V",j,",","V",k,")")

        # get `Y123_mean' etc.
        g <- paste0("Y",i,j,k,"_",FUN)

        # create the whole command
        command <- paste0("dt[,",g,":=",e,",by=",f,"]")

        # run command
        eval(parse(text = command))

        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in Similar terms:

```
foo = data.frame(Species=c(rep("A",4),"B",rep("C",3),"D","D"), 
             Effect=c(rep("Reproduction",3), rep("Growth",2),
                      "Reproduction", rep("Mortality",2), rep("Growth",2)), 
             Concentration=c(1.2,1.4,1.3,1.5,1.6,1.2,1.1,1,1.3,1.4))
```

Using package plyr:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(foo, .(Species,Effect), function(x) mean(x[,"Concentration"]))
```

You can also try:

```
 datDT <- data.table(foo, key="Species,Effect")
 datDT[, list(Concentration = mean(Concentration)), by = key(datDT)]
```

Sqldf solution:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Species, Effect,
  avg(Concentration) `Concentration`
  from foo
  group by Species, Effect")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this answers the OP's question. It's clear he knows how to do individual operations. His question seems to be on how to construct expressions for each time the loop is run so that he can get all the aggregations he requires.

Comment: @Prasannna, ddply is much slower than using data.table, hence I have a preference for data.table. I haven't tried sqldf, but not sure if a sql based solution will be faster than data.table. I would rather prefer a solution in data.table way, except that I need to get my syntax right